# Get element by id somar dois parágrafos

Tags: javascript

Quero somar os dois parágrafos com JavaScript (tag ou class), mas o resultado é sempre `NaN`.

```js
function calcular() {
    const num1 = document.getElementsByClassName("n1").value;
    const num2 = document.getElementsByClassName("n2").value;
    const elemResultado = document.getElementById("demo");
    const soma = parseInt(num1)+parseInt(num2);
    elemResultado.innerText = "O resultado é :"+soma;     
}
```

```css
input{
    size: 50px;
}

body{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border-style: double;
}
h1{
    font-family: algerian;
}
p#demo{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
 <h2>Some os valores abaixo:</h2>
 <p.n1> 2 </p>
 <p.n2> 5 </p>
 <p id="demo"></p>
 <button onclick="calcular();">Clique para calcular</button>
```

Comment: Você está pegando os elementos de forma errada, dá uma revisada no seu **HTML**.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` retorna uma "lista" de elementos e não apenas 1

Comment: como eu faço pra retornar 1?

Comment: @BKiller `getElementsByClassName` retorna sempre uma "lista", mas se apenas está interessado no primeiro elemento pode aceder a ele através da sintaxe de array com `[0]`, assim `document.getElementsByClassName("n1")[0].value`

Answer (score 1):

Seu código tem três problemas:

- Para adicionar classes ao HTML usa-se o atributo `class`, passando uma lista separada por espaços, por exemplo, `<span class="foo bar baz"></span>`
- `document.getElementByClassName` retorna um NodeList, ou seja, uma lista de elementos, ao acessar a propriedade `value` retorna `undefined`
- Para pegar o texto de um elemento que não seja uma entrada (`input`, `select`, etc) use `innerText` ou `innerHTML`

Código corrigido:

```js
function calcular() {
    const num1 = document.getElementsByClassName("n1")[0].innerText;
    const num2 = document.getElementsByClassName("n2")[0].innerText;
    const elemResultado = document.getElementById("demo");
    const soma = parseInt(num1)+parseInt(num2);
    elemResultado.innerText = "O resultado é :"+soma;     
}
```

```css
input{
    size: 50px;
}

body{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border-style: double;
}
h1{
    font-family: algerian;
}
p#demo{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some os valores abaixo:</h2>
 <p class="n1"> 2 </p>
 <p class="n2"> 5 </p>
 <p id="demo"></p>
 <button onclick="calcular();">Clique para calcular</button>
```

Uma ideia que pode ser interessante, em vez de pegar o primeiro elemento com a classe n1 e n2, você pode pegar todos os elementos com a classe n e usar um loop para soma-los:

```js
function calcular() {
    const num = document.getElementsByClassName("n");
    const elemResultado = document.getElementById("demo");

    let soma = 0;
    
    for (let n of num) {
        soma += parseInt(n.innerText);
    }

    elemResultado.innerText = "O resultado é :"+soma;     
}
```

```css
input{
    size: 50px;
}

body{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    border-style: double;
}
h1{
    font-family: algerian;
}
p#demo{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some os valores abaixo:</h2>
 <p class="n"> 2 </p>
 <p class="n"> 5 </p>
 <p class="n"> 3 </p>
 <p id="demo"></p>
 <button onclick="calcular();">Clique para calcular</button>
```